# how to increase Drop Down List capacity in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

How can you increase Drop Down List capacity in asp.net? I have to display 20,000 items in a single `DropDownList` but it not showing all items after binding. Some items are missing.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: **20'000** items in a single dropdown! Do your users like to pick from a list of 20'000 items ?!?!?

Comment: where is your code? what problem you have?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider doing some kind of search rather than displaying 20k items in a single dropdown.

Comment: 20,000.. ouch. Replace the drop down with some sort of autocomplete or search function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any direct limitation applied by the .NET framework; there may be a limit applied by the client, but I'm not sure.  20,000 is a lot of items and a lot of HTML to render, and HTML rendering is one of the bigger performance problems.  You may want to instead consider an alternative approach like an AutoComplete feature, [such as this](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason the dropdown list selection would be missing items.

Check your data source before binding to make sure all the items are there, it could be an issue with the query filling the data source rather than the dropdown list missing items.

Though as people have pointed out, replace this with either a search function or a autocomplete function dropdown lists should not be a place for 20,000 items.